# How to share components between VueJS projects in a Monorepo

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

in a single repository I have two VueJS single page applications which should share some components, a plugin and other common code. If changes are made to the common code, these should be immediately visible in both apps.

**My question(s):**
How can I solve this? Is there a canonical way to do this?

**The problems**

My simplistic approach was copying the code into the common dir and importing it with `../../common/my_component`. But this breaks relative imports as well as typing.

Converting shared stuff into npm modules breaks the auto update on change, doesn't it?

**More context:**

I am writing the apps in TypeScript.
npm link is no option as it must run

Right now the structure looks like this:

```
/ Main_Project
|-App1
| |- src
| |- ...
|-App2
| |- src
| |- ...
|-Common
| |- components
| |- plugins
| |- shared_code
```

Comment: Where is your `tsconfig.json` file located? Is it single for `Main_Project` or separate for each app?

Comment: It's a seperate one for each app. But they are identical.

Comment: Need some more info. Why is it breaking relative imports? We have a mono-repo setup with TypeScript and it works. Can you add more code snippets?

Comment: @wedi did you achieve to do this? Like not depending on a npm repo but your own monorepo?

Comment: I the end I did not need a solution as those two apps have been merged into one. Still, if you find a solution I'd be glad if you post how it worked for you. Maybe @HarshalPatil can help you with your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for me was to copy files from shared project into app projects.

**App1/package.json**:

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "shared": "copyfiles -u 4 -E ../Common/src/shared/**/*.* ./src/shared/"
},
"devDependencies": {
    ....
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1"
}
```

I run the command `npm run shared` in order to update project shared files after they were changed in `Common` project. It is not the best solution but it's simple, working and does not require much effort during the development.